# Has anybody experience with the new Google search API?

Tags: vb.net

I try to get search results from Google for images and I tried this tutorial.
https://hintdesk.com/2015/02/20/c-how-to-use-google-custom-search-api/

I also tried the code but it seems that this example is older and I get some errors.
The errors are at this points:

> ```
> Dim customSearchService = New CustomsearchService(New BaseClientService.Initializer With {.ApiKey = apiKey})
> ```
>
> ```
> Dim paging As IList(Of Result) = New List(Of Result)()
> ```

I am struggling to get this work and my question is if anybody has experience with that?

```
Imports GoogleSearchApi
Imports GoogleSearchApi.GoogleSearchClient
Imports GoogleSearchApi.GoogleSearchModel

Public Class Google
    Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
        Const apiKey As String = "My API Key"
        Const searchEngineId As String = "My Search Engine ID"
        Const query As String = "hintdesk"

        Dim customSearchService = New CustomsearchService(New BaseClientService.Initializer With {.ApiKey = apiKey})
        Dim listRequest = customSearchService.Cse.List(query)

        listRequest.Cx = searchEngineId
        Console.WriteLine("Start...")
        Dim paging As IList(Of Result) = New List(Of Result)()
        Dim count = 0

        While paging IsNot Nothing
        Console.WriteLine($"Page {count}")
            listRequest.Start = count * 10 + 1
            paging = listRequest.Execute().Items

            If paging IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each item In paging
                    Console.WriteLine("Title : " & item.Title + Environment.NewLine & "Link : " + item.Link + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine)
                Next
            End If

            count += 1
        End While

        Console.WriteLine("Done.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

now I get search results from Google using this version of my code.
The only problem is now that I am struggling with JSON to get the data.
In the results array it seems that I only get some header data and nothing about the search results.

JSON is quite new for me and it would be great if anybody could help please.

```
Public Shared Function Get_Google_Results(ByVal search As String) As Object

    Dim cx As String = "My custom search engine ID"
    Dim apiKey As String = "My API key"
    Dim request As WebRequest
    request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" & apiKey & "&cx=" & cx & "&q=" & search)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse
    response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseString As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    Dim jsonData
    jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString)

    Dim results As New List(Of String)

    For Each i In jsonData

        results.Add(New String(i.ToString))

    Next

    Return results

End Function
```